# What is uncontrolled input field in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, warnings

What does it mean when React says **input field is an uncontrolled field`**? How it will affect the web page with a form of uncontrolled input fields. I can see a warning message in the console while changing values of the field, other than that what are other issues going to be there on the application?

Comment: It always helps to directly quote (and link to if possible) the error message/page/documentation you're referring to.

Comment: Top hit on the search "uncontrolled input site:reactjs.org" for me on two different search engines: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An uncontrolled input is simply one where you're not using React to control the input's value (e.g, you don't use `value={this.state.value}` or similar); instead, you use a ref and get the value from the DOM directly. This means the DOM contains the "source of truth" for that piece of state, rather than your React model containing the source of truth for it.

React documentation links:

- [Uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)
- [Forms (including controlled components)](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Answer (score 2):

From my limited understanding, a "Controlled" input is when you use react state to 'control' the input's value (usually by assigning the value attribute to a state variable and handling changes to the input by updating the state). An "uncontrolled" input is one where the value is not determined by the state and operates independently. These inputs and their values are usually accessed using Refs.

Perhaps this sample will help clarify things better. This is a simple app which has one controlled and one uncontrolled input.

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/326pwm74x5)

Sample Code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    value: ""
    };
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
}
handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
    value: e.target.value
    });
};
handleRefChange = e => {
    const el = this.inputRef.current;
    // Handle value here as needed
    console.log(el.value);
};
render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>Controlled vs Uncontrolled Inputs</h1>
        <h2>Controlled</h2>
        <label for="controlled">Controlled</label>
        <input
        id="controlled"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        value={this.state.value}
        type="text"
        />
        <p> Value: {this.state.value} </p>

        <h2>Uncontrolled</h2>
        <label for="uncontrolled">Controlled</label>
        <input
        id="uncontrolled"
        onChange={this.handleRefChange}
        ref={this.inputRef}
        type="text"
        />
    </div>
    );
}
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

References:

[Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

[Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)